# Not able to add project reference of .Net Core 2.0 project to Azure functions project(netStandard2.0)

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using Visual studio 2017 v-15.6.0. my services present in core 2.0 project. i am trying to refer core 2.0 services to azure functions Project(netStandard2.0) Which is not Supporting.
I am getting below Error.
'netcoreapp2.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'.
Could you please help me to move forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is entirely correct. netcoreapp2.0 is a *framework* target; netstandard2.0 is a *standard* target. Multiple different frameworks implement the same standard, which means that something that targets a standard can't know what framework it will be running on. As such:

- a project that targets a framework can reference a library that references either the same framework, or a standard that that framework implements - i.e. a netcoreapp2.0 project can reference netcoreapp2.0 or netstandard2.0 libraries
- a library that targets a standard can reference other libraries that target that standard - i.e. a netstandard2.0 library can reference a netstandard2.0 library

If your project targets netstandard2.0 and the thing you want to reference only targets netcoreapp2.0, then that isn't going to work; either:

- you can change *your project* to target the framework: netcoreapp2.0
- if you control the library, you can try changing the *referenced library* to target the standard: netstandard2.0

Comment: Thank you for Quick response Marc Gravell. Can we able to Create Azure Functions in Core 2.0?

Comment: Hi @Marc Gravell  Can we able to create Azure functions in core 2.0?

Comment: Azure Functions v2 runs on .NET core 2.0 but the current tooling in Visual Studio only lets you create the application as a .NET standard 2.0 class library. You could manually create a .NET core class library that defines your functions but you will run into some tooling issues (for example, a build task must generate function.json and that build task only works for .NET standard class libraries). In summary - if you want to use the functions VS tooling, you'll need to reference .NET standard class libraries, not .NET core.